# Databinding in Listview object inside an object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a small listview and want to display data from a list of objects in it. The object has another object, whos data should be displayed too. The code looks like this.

XAML: Small LisView with 3 3 Columns and binding:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstOrder" Margin="10,9,10,10">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header= "Customer" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path= customerName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header= "Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path= date}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header= "Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path= priceSum}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Data shall be taken from the class Order:

```
public class Order
{
    public Customer customer;
    public string date { get; set; }
    public double priceSum { get; set; }
}
```

Date and price can be bound easily and are shown in the application, but customer name can't.

Basically I got two questions.

1. Is there any problem declaring a proberty for an object?
2. How can I access data within customer to display it in a ListView?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind to member fields, so turn `public Customer customer;` into a property `public Customer customer {get;set;}` instead. Then specify the binding path with dots `{Binding Path=customer.Name}`

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following:

```
<GridViewColumn Header= "Customer" 
  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path= Customer.CustomerName}"/>
```

i.e. Customer.propertyName

in your case -> customer.customerName (it should match the property name of parent as well as the child as it is case sensitive)